# How to manipulate internal image?

Tags: graphics

I know that external images can be manipulated using the \includegraphics command and its options. How about images that are provided with packages? For example, is it possible to enlarge the "Regional Indicator Symbol Letter A" \twemoji{1f1e6} and crop a square area in the middle then embed the cropped area in a empty square box?

Answer (score 2):

For example, in OpTeX, you can do:

```
\load[emoji]
\newbox\myA
\setbox\myA=\hbox{\roundness=0pt 
   \clipinoval 9.5pt 7.5pt 15pt 15pt {\setfontsize{at20pt}\emojifont }}

\noindent
\copy\myA, \copy\myA, \copy\myA. % prints , ,  but with sharp corners.

\bye
```

and external images are loaded by `\inspic`. Maybe, you are searching for LaTeX solution, no OpTeX solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trimclip`. Since it seems you want to clip the same amount from all sides (possibly in order to get rid of the rounded corners), you can just specify a fraction of the width. See the manual of `trimclip` (note that “site” should be “side”).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\begin{document}

\twemoji{1f1e6}

{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\clipbox{{0.1\width}}{\twemoji{1f1e6}}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the particular case of `twemojis`, you can use the optional argument to pass different options to `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{twemojis}

\newcommand{\clippedtwemoji}[1]{%
  \twemoji[%
    height=\twemojiDefaultHeight,
    trim={0.1\twemojiDefaultHeight} {0.1\twemojiDefaultHeight}
         {0.1\twemojiDefaultHeight} {0.1\twemojiDefaultHeight},
    clip,
  ]{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\boxedclippedtwemoji}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4pt}%
  \fbox{\clippedtwemoji{#1}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\twemoji{1f1e6}

\clippedtwemoji{1f1e6}

\boxedclippedtwemoji{1f1e6}

\end{document}
```

[image]